# How do I attach the enum value to an object, instead of the enum name?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

So my title is probably not the best one, but I think I can better show it in code what I want to achieve. I'm doing things with Spring Boot, JPA and React.

So let's say I have this enum:

```java
public enum MyEnum {
  FIRST_ENUM("First"),
  SECOND_ENUM("Second")
}
```

And there's a class that contains one of the enums:

```java
public class MyClass {
  private int id;
  private MyEnum myEnum;
}
```

When I convert an instance of this class to JSON (so I can pass it to React as JSON), this is what I get:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "myEnum": "FIRST_ENUM"
}
```

But instead I want it to use the value instead (I know I can manually create JSONObject instances, but is there a way to automatically use the value instead?):

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "myEnum": "First"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST_ENUM("First"),
    SECOND_ENUM("Second");

    @JsonValue
    private final String name;

    MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static MyEnum fromString(String string) {
        ...//find enum constant by name
    }
}
```

Comment: That was fast! This did exactly what I needed.

Did you know how to do this or did you find it? Just wondering if I'm bad at Googling or not :D

Comment: I used it extensively in some projects. As a side note, Jackson docs claim `@JsonValue` should be enough, it never worked for me without `@JsonCreator`, though

Comment: I was about to do completely something else and ditch enums, but now I will know it can be done this way then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `@JsonProperty` for the enum values if the purpose of the custom `name` is to represent the enum's value in JSON:

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    @JsonProperty("First")  FIRST_ENUM,
    @JsonProperty("Second") SECOND_ENUM;
}
```